# Create 2 records in 2 tables consistently using MySQL/InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

Consider I have two tables, **t1** and **t2**

> t1 = (id, name), t2 = (id, fid)

The **fid** in t2 is a Foreign Key to **t1**.

Steps to create rows as following.

1. Insert a row in t1, get the id
2. Use that id and insert as fid in t2.

**My problem is:**

Since t1's id is unknow when the transaction is not committed, so how to perform the insertion to t2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If id is auto-incremented in table1 then you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (name) VALUES ('whatever');
INSERT INTO t2 (fid) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

This comes from the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

EDIT: How about if I am inserting 3 tables t1, t2, t3 Both t2 and t3 have a fid equal to t1. But when t3 insert the fid, the LAST_INSERT_ID() is belong to t2, not t1.

Then you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (name) VALUES ('whatever');
SET @id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO t2 (fid) VALUES (@id);
INSERT INTO t3 (fid) VALUES (@id);
...
```

Comment: Indeed, the new id in t1 **is** known. On a concurrent other transaction (and possibly a rollback or commit) there could be a gap in the sequence of id's, which shouldn't matter.

Comment: How about if I am inserting 3 tables

t1, t2, t3

Both t2 and t3 have a fid equal to t1.

But when t3 insert the fid, the LAST_INSERT_ID() is belong to t2, not t1.

Comment: I have edited my post to answer this different question.  You just save the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and then retrieve it when you need it.

Comment: Thanks. I voted you as the correct answer.

Last question, do you think it is also safe to use program to handle the last_insert_id?

e.g.

$db->execute("INSERT INTO t1 (name) VALUES ('whatever')");
$id = $db->get_last_insert_id();
$db->execute("INSERT INTO t2 (fid) VALUES ('" . $id . "')");
$db->execute("INSERT INTO t3 (fid) VALUES ('" . $id . "')");

Comment: @Yoga That should be fine.  They probably have the same semantics.